# How to compare two strings in sql in natural order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I had a quick question.

I need to compare two strings in SQL in natural order. So if I have a string like ‘20091210’ and ‘20101213’ then the latter would be greater. The string could also contain alpha characters so ‘Y4550’ would be greater than ‘Y4500’. I tried using the CHECKSUM system function to convert the string to a hashed number but that isn’t giving me a number with regard to natural order.

Do you know of anything that I can use aside from making a CLR function?

Comment: What are you doing to do with the comapriason?  How are the SQL native comparisons failing you?

Comment: I think the SQL native compare function will serve you well in the examples you cited. Where it gets into real trouble is comparing `Y2` and `Y10`--`Y2` will be the "greater" string. To resolve this, you can split the string if they are in consistent format, like always `Y####`. Otherwise, CLR is the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question right, you want to compare two string columns in the same row, or a column with a variable. For that, you can simply use the `<` and `>` operators:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username > 'Tom'
```

That will return any users whose username falls alphabetically after "Tom."

If we were talking about multiple records, `ORDER BY` will do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY Username
```

That will sort users by their username, in ascending alphabetical order.